A Teen Movie where the main girl character is a tomboy who, I think, is a mechanic
The film I am thinking of is probably in the Teen Movie Genre and would have been made in the 1980s or early 90s.  It was definitely set in America around the same period so was a contemporary film.
I can't remember any of the actors or the plot, sadly.  It involved a group of high school friends and I think the plot was centred around the relationship between a boy and a girl.  I remember in one scene there was a party and a group of guys were being very intimidating and causing trouble until one of the group of school-friends (a 'mountain' of a guy) turns up and something he says makes the troublemakers think twice.  I think they leave before there is any violence.
I do remember at the end, the girl, who I think may have dropped out from school to become a mechanic is walking down the road in the dark.  She is wearing jeans and a leather jacket and has short hair.  She is a tomboy by nature.  Suddenly, the boy she likes runs after her and it transpires that he has just realises that she likes him.  She is overwhelmed that he has come to this realisation.  The final shots are of him picking her up and spinning her and kissing and they walk off together into the moonlight.
I hope there is something there in the two scenes I can remember a bit of for someone to be able to identify the movie.

Lol, Transformers? http://www.imdb.com/media/rm3275656960/ch0003326

The 1987 film Some Kind of Wonderful fits this. The tomboy is played by Mary Stuart Masterson, and she is a drummer and a mechanic.
 
At the end of the movie the guy (Eric Stoltz) realizes they were meant to be together.
Here is the trailer which shows nearly every point you mentioned including the "picking her up and spinning her and kissing" at the end.

There actually was a movie mid-eighties that was called "Tomboy" and was about a teenage girl automechanic:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090184/
I've never seen it, though, so couldn't comment on whether or not any of the scenes match. YouTube has a grainy trailer if you'd like to watch it to see if it's familiar:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofi8IlQJz1w

Thank you so much!  I don't think this is the one though as the plot says that the male lead tries to win her over and the impression that remains with me from the movie is that the lead girl has fallen for the lead male, but doesn't think he feels the same way for her because she is tomboyish. The final scene is a feel good one when she realises that he does feel for her.  I haven't been able to check the trailer out on youtube yet as it is playing up for some reason, but I will watch it.  The stills from the film look a bit too clean and the girl looks too feminine.  Thank you though! :-)
